# Exchange formula of 2-form or n-form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

I only know the exchange formula of 1-form is that 
$\nabla_i\nabla_j v_kdx^k-\nabla_j\nabla_iv_kdx^k=g^{lm}R_{ijkl}v_mdx^m$.

But in the below picture, only  exchange formula of 1-form seems be not enough.

How to compute the second equal (part of red line) ?

[image]

Comment: You need to use RIcci identity for tensor.

Comment: There is not Ricci identity on Wiki....

Comment: I mean the one with a T [(click here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Coordinate_expression) in the wiki.

Comment: Unlucky, the discuss of paper has been move to tomorrow afternoon, hope I can compute it...

Comment: So you are going to presenting this paper?

Comment: @JohnMa  Yes, but only about  ten pages of the front part of the paper.

Comment: I think I have got the answer.

Comment: That's good to know.